# How to write string as unicode byte in python?

Tags: python-3.x, unicode

When i write '你' in agend and save it as test-unicode.txt in unicode mode,open it with `xxd g:\\test-unicode.txt` ,i got :

```
0000000: fffe 604f                                ..`O
```

1.fffe stand for little endian
2.the unicode of `你`  is `\x4f\x60`

I want to write the `你` as `604f` or `4f60` in the file.

```
output=open("g://test-unicode.txt","wb")
str1="你"
output.write(str1)
output.close()
```

error:

```
TypeError: 'str' does not support the buffer interface
```

When i change it into the following ,there is no errror.

```
output=open("g://test-unicode.txt","wb")
str1="你"
output.write(str1.encode())
output.close()
```

when open it with `xxd g:\\test-unicode.txt` ,i got :

```
0000000: e4bd a0                                  ...
```

How can i write  `604f` or `4f60` into my file the same way as microsoft aengda do(save as unicode format)?

Comment: it is not good to take english as an example,i change it as chinese.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Unicode" as an encoding is actually [UTF-16LE](http://www.unicode.org/glossary/#UTF_16LE).

```
with open("g:/test-unicode.txt", "w", encoding="utf-16le") as output:
  output.write(str1)
```

Comment: I have tried there is a bug in it ,it should be `with open("g:/test-unicode.txt", "w", encoding="utf-16le") as output:` not `with open("g:/test-unicode.txt", "wb", encoding="utf-16le") as output:`.

Comment: @it_is_a_literature: Right, fixed.